# How can I send decimal value from caller window to window that will be called/opened on click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm wondering how can I send value from one window to another, basically on callers window I calculate something and I want to send it to another window which will display
that amount I calculated on previous window..

What I imagined but I don't know is that best approach is next:
I created property on second window which will display informations and gave it a value from first window, like this:

/
/CALLER WINDOW - MAIN WINDOW

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            double sum = 0;

            foreach (var item in myGrid)
            {
                sum += Convert.ToDouble(item.TotalAmount);
            }

            TestWindow change = new TestWindow();
            change.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(sum);
            change.ShowDialog();
}
```

TestWindow (second window which must display sum from previous display)

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
        public decimal Total;

        public TestWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtDisplayAmount.Text = Total.ToString();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        }
}
```

**But it allways displays a zero!**

Comment: TestWindow() is called on "new" ... All of that code runs prior to you setting change.Total = {...}. When you set the Total, you don't update the textbox. You can either public function to update it, which sets Total and then sets txtDisplayAmount.Text, you can change Total to a Property with a Setter that updates txtDisplayAmount.Text, or you can create an initiator that takes the total in, and set it accordingly... Or you could do it with bindings - there are a bunch of ways. End result - txtDisplayAmount.Text = {...} needs to be called *after* Total is set.

Comment: Don't mix `decimal` with `double`, they're completely different datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the value the window when you create it:

**MainWindow:**

```
TestWindow change = new TestWindow(Convert.ToDecimal(sum));
change.ShowDialog();
```

**TestWindow:**

```
public TestWindow(decimal total)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtDisplayAmount.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

If you intend to change the value at a later time, you could use a property but then you should make sure that the `TextBox` is updated whenever the property is set:

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDisplayAmount))
                return 0M;

            decimal d;
            decimal.TryParse(txtDisplayAmount.Text, out d);
            return d;
        }
        set { txtDisplayAmount.Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: In general is there any 'better' way of passing values between windows or this is ok?

Comment: This is known as constructor injection and it is a perfectly valid approach: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection. If you want to be able to change the value dynamically after the window has been created, you should use a property.

Comment: Thanks mm8 this is allright. Can you explain how come in example I posted, value of Total is allways zero.. Thanks one more time

Comment: Because the constructor returns, and the Text property is set, before you set the Total property.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to directly pass a value from 1 form to another or even change the values between different forms.

try these changes in your main window:

```
public double sum = 0;   /// it's important to declare the public variable outside of the click event. use the event only to change it's value.

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
        foreach (var item in myGrid)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToDouble(item.TotalAmount);
        }

        TestWindow change = new TestWindow();
        change.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(sum);
        change.ShowDialog();
}
```

now in your test window try this code:

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public decimal Total;

    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtDisplayAmount.Text = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).sum.ToString();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That is because when the constructor of **TestWindow** is launched, Total property of TestWindow is zero. Pass in the argument of value into the constructor and assigned it there.